# Throttle a detail view in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, throttling

I have a custom throttle:

```
from rest_framework.throttling import UserRateThrottle

class OncePerDayUserThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
   rate = '1/day'
```

I use this throttle in a class api view as such:

```
class PostHitCount(APIView):
   throttle_classes = [OncePerDayUserThrottle]

   def post(self, request, hitcount_pk, format=None):
       # my post method
```

The url corresponding to this view is

```
path('add-hitcount/<int:hitcount_pk>/', PostHitCount.as_view())
```

If i access this view for the first time via url *add-count/1/*, i am permitted.
If i later post to the same url, i am not permitted (which is ok!).

Now if i post to the url *add-count/2/*, the request is rejected since the user already accessed that view!

How can i permit requests with another detail url?

Also, is it possible to set the throttle rate to say **1/year** or even **1/lifetime** ? How ?

Comment: Why aren't i getting any help? 

Comment: my solution below should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to override the "get_cache_key" method.

```
from rest_framework.throttling import UserRateThrottle

class OncePerDayUserThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    rate = '1/day'
    cache_format = 'throttle_%(scope)s_%(ident)s_%(detail)s'

    def get_cache_key(self, request, view):
        """
        Limits the rate of API calls that may be made by a given user.

        The user id will be used as a unique cache key if the user is
        authenticated.  For anonymous requests, the IP address of the request will
        be used.
        """
        scope = 'user'

        def get_cache_key(self, request, view):
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                ident = request.user.pk
            else:
                ident = self.get_ident(request)

            return self.cache_format % {
                'scope': self.scope,
                'ident': ident,
                'detail': view.kwargs.get("hitcount_pk")
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this?
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#userratethrottle

You need to use a "scope":

```
class BurstRateThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    scope = 'burst'

class SustainedRateThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    scope = 'sustained'
```

And define the scope in settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        'example.throttles.BurstRateThrottle',
        'example.throttles.SustainedRateThrottle'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'burst': '60/min',
        'sustained': '1000/day'
    }
}
```